# Issue in reputation calculation and new achievement notification?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Two days back when my rep was somewhere between 92-98, I got the new notification in my achievement that I have earned "edit community wiki" privilege but it was granted on the rep of 100.  Again, today in the morning my rep was 122 and I got down voted thrice so it became 116. Then I corrected my answer and got an upvote three times and rep became 122 again. At that time, in my achievements I saw that I have earned a privilege to "vote down" which is granted on the rep of 125.  So my confusion is that whether it is a bug or something else?

Comment: How do you know those were upvotes and not downvotes that got reversed?

Comment: Because I answered some question in a hurry which was not correct and I know I got down voted for that only. As soon as I correct the answer I got up votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are granted permissions the moment you reach a certain rep level. The privilege is lost if you drop below the threshold again. You get a notification when reached the privilege, but no such notification is sent when you lose it again.

This means you can reach a permission for a short period of time if, for example, someone upvotes one of your posts *then undoes the vote again*. Perhaps someone accidentally upvoted your answer, then realised their mistake and changed it to a downvote instead. You'd have gone from 122 to 132 (and be granted the permission), then go down to 120 as the upvote is changed to a downvote. To simplify your reputation record, only the final vote is shown, if the vote change occurred within the same day.

This is unfortunate, but not a bug.

Comment: Does this frequent up vote and down vote reflects in notification? Because in my case it doesn't.

Comment: @ricky: Clarified that some more. No, the notification doesn't reflect that, nor does your reputation history.

Comment: **To simplify your reputation record, only the final vote is shown**  This line cleared my confusion. Thanks @Martijn Pieters for the response.